# Move data with AWS RDS PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have multiple PostgreSQL databases running in RDS. Now, I need to move data from these multiple databases to one master database, within the same RDS instance. What options could you suggest that I should look into? I am planning to consider the following:

1. Using Lambda to read data from the multiple databases and write the data back to the master database.
2. I can use Data Pipelines to move the data around the places.

Anything else that I should consider for the use case?

Answer (score 0):

I would use DMS (https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) it will copy the data and keep it in sync until you're ready to switch over.